# How to remove ASP.NET MVC controller name from angular route

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC login page and on login button click, it is redirecting to  another page which is connected with angular, Once I  logged in, the url redirecting me to something like below 
 http://localhost:5083/Home#/home

I need to remove the ASP MVC controller name ("Home") from the Url, how can i do that?

[image]

Angular Routing Config
[image]

ASP.NET MVC Routing Config
[image]

Login page location -  AccountContrller->Index.cshtml and on login button click it moved 
to HomeController -->index.cshtml

Comment: Is Login action in HomeController? Could you please provide the angular route config as well?

Comment: @Developer please refer the updated question.. Thanks and regards

Comment: might be worth your while to check this out, seeing that you are trying to mix mvc and angular http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/mvc-routing-with-angularjs-routing/

Comment: @AslamJiffry- In that case, I think your MVC default route is not pointing to HomeController. Should work as you expect if you point MVC default route to Home and Index.
This is what happens:
- request comes to localhost:5083
- MVC resolves the default route
- request reached Home controller -. Index action
- where it returns the view which bootstraps angularjs
- works according to angularjs route

Comment: @Developer  ---  HomeController is working and both angular and MVC routing perfectly working, my concern is to remove the ASP MVC controller name ("Home") from the URL, as i think it should handle from ASP MVC routing but i dont have a clue to fix it.

Comment: What I meant was, if MVC default route is pointing to Home controller and Index action, then localhost:5083/#/home will work

Comment: @Developer, ASP.NET MVC  Route config updated in the question. Default route is configured for login screen, when click on the login button it redirects to Index action method in HomeController.ng-view tag included Index view in HomeController. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: so define "Home" as a default

Comment: @AlekseyL.  If I put HomeController as default route, it works but loginController view get  skipped. could't see the login screen it directly goes to Index view in HomeController.  thanks.

Comment: For Login , give specific route-> localhost:5083/Login and let the default route be Home. When user navigates to localhost:5083 then check whether the user is authroized, and if not redirect to Login.

Comment: @Developer .. Thanks Now its working as per the above suggestion..Put that as answer.

Comment: @AlekseyL.  Thanks for the support and suggession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your MVC default route so that it points to Home controller and action as Index - so when request comes as localhost:5083, mvc will resolve the controller as Home and action as Index, which will inturn bootstrap the angularjs routing.

Answer (score 0):

In the page provided by MVC (Home/Index.cshtml), if you set the Base Href to /Home then angular2 will be able to route everything relative to /Home and then you don't need to remove /Home from the URL, so at the top of Index.cshtml add:

```
<head>
<base href="/Home/"
```

Comment: where should I include this? within the partial view or index.cshtml which include <ng-view> ?.. I included that in Home/Index.cshtml, But as a result  routing system didn't work.. thanks & regards

Comment: It should go in the index.cshtml, but this won't work if you use default route of Home as you have discussed in the comments in the original post. Here is an article discussing base href: http://www.verdantrefuge.com/writing/2013/angularjs-changing-app-path-base-element/